# API examples using JSON PATCH for partial updates

Tags: rest, patch

I'm looking for the best solution to apply a partial update to an object with a REST API (ASP.NET)

I originally wanted to use "JSON Merge Patch" format ([rfc7396](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396.txt)), but I was not able to do it with ASP.NET (hard to differentiate ignored fields, and fields set to null)

I tried to use PATCH with JSON PATCH format and it is working.

Ex. :

```
[
    { "op": "replace", "path": "/Name", "value": "patchedValue" },
    { "op": "replace", "path": "/EnumTest", "value": "blo" },
    { "op": "replace", "path": "/SubItem/Name", "value": "patchedValue" }
]
```

I see that Microsoft support this format ([asp.net core json patch](https://github.com/aspnet/JsonPatch)), but I have no idea if this format is often used. I don't want to be the only one using it... I'm looking for API from big companies that is using this format for partial update. Do you have some examples ?